# REPLACE with INNER JOIN SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
FROM   
    DW_Stage.PreStage.FilteredCoupon  c
INNER JOIN 
    DW.Linkage l WITH (nolock)
          REPLACE([l.CouponNumber], '/', '') ON (c.CouponSeqNbr = l.CouponNumber 
                                             AND c.PNRCreateDate = l.PNRCreateDate 
                                             AND c.PNRLocator = l.PNRLocator 
                                             AND c.PrimaryDocNbr = l.PrimaryDocNbr)
```

So there are two records that have a '/' in CouponNumber which is causing my SSIS package to fail. If i use this REPLACE function would this be the best use of it? Or should the REPLACE function be used in the ON part? Thanks

Comment: replace on the join

Comment: You should include the SSIS tag on this posting.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `replace()` in the `on` part.  Your syntax makes no sense.  But you also want to remove the square braces:

```
FROM DW_Stage.PreStage.FilteredCoupon c INNER JOIN
     DW.Linkage l
     ON c.CouponSeqNbr = REPLACE(l.CouponNumber, '/', '') AND
        c.PNRCreateDate = l.PNRCreateDate AND
        c.PNRLocator = l.PNRLocator AND
        c.PrimaryDocNbr = l.PrimaryDocNbr
```

The parentheses arond the `ON` conditions also add no value.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM   
          DW_Stage.PreStage.FilteredCoupon  c
          INNER JOIN 
          DW.Linkage l WITH (nolock)


              ON 
          (     
         c.CouponSeqNbr = REPLACE([l.CouponNumber], '/', '')
        AND c.PNRCreateDate = l.PNRCreateDate 
        AND c.PNRLocator = l.PNRLocator 
        AND c.PrimaryDocNbr = l.PrimaryDocNbr )
```